# Why the button event of a web user control does not fire?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascx, web-user-controls

My web user control is

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbList" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDoSub" runat="server"/>
```

in my webpage, at the Init part, i add the control into a panel dynamically

```
 Private Sub Webpage_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
      Panel1.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("controls/MyControl.ascx"))
 End sub
```

The problem now is that the click event does not fire upon clicking at the button.

So what am i doing wrong here? How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give this control an ID while adding it to the panel.